# Jetpack Compose - tap coordinates don't match rectangle coordinates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose

So I am trying to detect touch events when one rectangle is selected. Unfortunately, my x, y coordinates do not match the rectangle coordinates when I click on the rectangle, so it is never selected.

This is my code:

```
Image(bitmap = imageBitmap, "New Image", Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onPress = { it ->
                        val x = it.x
                        val y = it.y

                        println("x = $x and y = $y")

                        for ((index, value) in updatedList.value?.withIndex()!!) {

                            val rect = RectF(
                                value.offset.x,
                                value.offset.y,
                                value.offset.x + value.size.width,
                                value.offset.y + value.size.height
                            )

                            println("left = ${rect.left}")
                            println("top = ${rect.top}")
                            println("right = ${rect.right}")
                            println("bottom = ${rect.bottom}")

                            for (i in index until updatedList.value!!.size) {
                                if (x > rect.left
                                    && x < rect.right
                                    && y > rect.top
                                    && y < rect.bottom
                                ) {
                                    println("Touched at index $index")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                )
            }
```

If I click on the rectangle I get this:

```
I/System.out: x = 339.96582 and y = 192.96289
I/System.out: left = 215.0
I/System.out: top = 210.0
I/System.out: right = 220.0
I/System.out: bottom = 280.0
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: what is updatedList ?

Comment: It's a liveData value that is being observed. Basically, as soon as a new rectangle is added, the list is updated.

Comment: And the list looks like this: ```                rectList.add(
                    RectData(
                        size = Size(
                            word.length.toFloat(), textBounds.height().toFloat()
                        ), offset = Offset(
                            xCoordinate.toFloat(),
                            yCoordinate.toFloat()
                        )
                    )
                )
                viewModel.onListChanged(rectList)```

Comment: ok, your question pointed me in the right direction. Basically: word.length is not a pixel value. Thanks.